# How can i group this data in postgresql?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, query-optimization

I have a table with millions of data. I'm having trouble making reports on data.

This is the table I have:

```
"channel_id"    "datetime"  "parameter" "raw"
10  "2022-12-02 16:16:00"   "Günlük Debi"   3423.89
9   "2022-12-02 16:16:00"   "KABIN NEM" 36.27
8   "2022-12-02 16:16:00"   "KABIN SICAKLIK"    20.18
7   "2022-12-02 16:16:00"   "AKM"   4.54
6   "2022-12-02 16:16:00"   "KOi"   24.4
5   "2022-12-02 16:16:00"   "AkisHizi"  0.59
4   "2022-12-02 16:16:00"   "Sicaklik"  13.53
3   "2022-12-02 16:16:00"   "Debi"  3.04
2   "2022-12-02 16:16:00"   "CozunmusOksijen"   5.05
1   "2022-12-02 16:16:00"   "Iletkenlik"    1125.64
0   "2022-12-02 16:16:00"   "pH"    7.09
9   "2022-12-02 16:17:00"   "KABIN NEM" 20.22
8   "2022-12-02 16:17:00"   "KABIN SICAKLIK"    6.49
7   "2022-12-02 16:17:00"   "AKM"   6.36
6   "2022-12-02 16:17:00"   "KOi"   30.12
5   "2022-12-02 16:17:00"   "AkisHizi"  0.82
4   "2022-12-02 16:17:00"   "Sicaklik"  20.36
3   "2022-12-02 16:17:00"   "Debi"  16.15
2   "2022-12-02 16:17:00"   "CozunmusOksijen"   2.45
1   "2022-12-02 16:17:00"   "Iletkenlik"    1570.75
0   "2022-12-02 16:17:00"   "pH"    7.48
7   "2022-12-02 16:13:00"   "AKM"   16.02
6   "2022-12-02 16:13:00"   "KOi"   25.98
5   "2022-12-02 16:13:00"   "AkisHizi"  0.83
4   "2022-12-02 16:13:00"   "Sicaklik"  17.87
3   "2022-12-02 16:13:00"   "Debi"  27.85
2   "2022-12-02 16:13:00"   "CozunmusOksijen"   5.91
1   "2022-12-02 16:13:00"   "Iletkenlik"    2221.36
0   "2022-12-02 16:13:00"   "pH"    7.25
9   "2022-12-02 16:14:00"   "KABIN NEM" 62.28
8   "2022-12-02 16:14:00"   "KABIN SICAKLIK"    13.99
7   "2022-12-02 16:14:00"   "AKM"   6.02
6   "2022-12-02 16:14:00"   "KOi"   21.36
5   "2022-12-02 16:14:00"   "AkisHizi"  0.56
4   "2022-12-02 16:14:00"   "Sicaklik"  21.6
3   "2022-12-02 16:14:00"   "Debi"  10.35
2   "2022-12-02 16:14:00"   "CozunmusOksijen"   0.32
1   "2022-12-02 16:14:00"   "Iletkenlik"    7325.54
0   "2022-12-02 16:14:00"   "pH"    7.57
10  "2022-12-02 16:15:00"   "Günlük Debi"   5363.51
9   "2022-12-02 16:15:00"   "KABIN NEM" 34.65
8   "2022-12-02 16:15:00"   "KABIN SICAKLIK"    20.25
7   "2022-12-02 16:15:00"   "AKM"   6.52
6   "2022-12-02 16:15:00"   "KOi"   12.71
5   "2022-12-02 16:15:00"   "AkisHizi"  0.54
4   "2022-12-02 16:15:00"   "Sicaklik"  14.41
3   "2022-12-02 16:15:00"   "Debi"  5.09
2   "2022-12-02 16:15:00"   "CozunmusOksijen"   5.86
1   "2022-12-02 16:15:00"   "Iletkenlik"    1933.55
0   "2022-12-02 16:15:00"   "pH"    7.24
7   "2022-12-02 16:13:00"   "AKM"   38.64
6   "2022-12-02 16:13:00"   "KOi"   26.17
5   "2022-12-02 16:13:00"   "AkisHizi"  0.52
4   "2022-12-02 16:13:00"   "Sicaklik"  12.46
3   "2022-12-02 16:13:00"   "Debi"  1.32
2   "2022-12-02 16:13:00"   "CozunmusOksijen"   9.06
1   "2022-12-02 16:13:00"   "Iletkenlik"    2566.5
0   "2022-12-02 16:13:00"   "pH"    7.33
9   "2022-12-02 16:14:00"   "KABIN NEM" 21.71
8   "2022-12-02 16:14:00"   "KABIN SICAKLIK"    16.5
7   "2022-12-02 16:14:00"   "AKM"   12.56
6   "2022-12-02 16:14:00"   "KOi"   18.64
5   "2022-12-02 16:14:00"   "AkisHizi"  0.63
4   "2022-12-02 16:14:00"   "Sicaklik"  12.56
3   "2022-12-02 16:14:00"   "Debi"  4.84
2   "2022-12-02 16:14:00"   "CozunmusOksijen"   2.15
1   "2022-12-02 16:14:00"   "Iletkenlik"    621.05
0   "2022-12-02 16:14:00"   "pH"    5.16
9   "2022-12-02 16:14:00"   "KABIN NEM" 20.65
8   "2022-12-02 16:14:00"   "KABIN SICAKLIK"    21.32
7   "2022-12-02 16:14:00"   "AKM"   9.28
6   "2022-12-02 16:14:00"   "KOi"   23.24
5   "2022-12-02 16:14:00"   "AkisHizi"  0.63
4   "2022-12-02 16:14:00"   "Sicaklik"  12.79
3   "2022-12-02 16:14:00"   "Debi"  3.09
2   "2022-12-02 16:14:00"   "CozunmusOksijen"   2.53
1   "2022-12-02 16:14:00"   "Iletkenlik"    1473.54
0   "2022-12-02 16:14:00"   "pH"    7.69
10  "2022-12-02 16:14:00"   "Günlük Debi"   8453.81
9   "2022-12-02 16:14:00"   "KABIN NEM" 32.88
8   "2022-12-02 16:14:00"   "KABIN SICAKLIK"    24.88
7   "2022-12-02 16:14:00"   "AKM"   6.16
6   "2022-12-02 16:14:00"   "KOi"   51.93
5   "2022-12-02 16:14:00"   "AkisHizi"  0.54
4   "2022-12-02 16:14:00"   "Sicaklik"  17.91
3   "2022-12-02 16:14:00"   "Debi"  9.3
2   "2022-12-02 16:14:00"   "CozunmusOksijen"   2.69
1   "2022-12-02 16:14:00"   "Iletkenlik"    2318.17
0   "2022-12-02 16:14:00"   "pH"    7.27
10  "2022-12-02 16:14:00"   "Günlük Debi"   3342.46
9   "2022-12-02 16:14:00"   "KABIN NEM" 57.81
8   "2022-12-02 16:14:00"   "KABIN SICAKLIK"    42.21
7   "2022-12-02 16:14:00"   "AKM"   14.7
6   "2022-12-02 16:14:00"   "KOi"   38.02
5   "2022-12-02 16:14:00"   "AkisHizi"  0.61
4   "2022-12-02 16:14:00"   "Sicaklik"  19.88
3   "2022-12-02 16:14:00"   "Debi"  3.39
2   "2022-12-02 16:14:00"   "CozunmusOksijen"   3.94
1   "2022-12-02 16:14:00"   "Iletkenlik"    901.02
0   "2022-12-02 16:14:00"   "pH"    7.33
```

The result I want to achieve is like this:

```
datetime        values
2022-12-02 16:16:00     [{..PULSAR,Günlük Debi,3423.89},{...GENTEK...}...]
2022-12-02 16:17:00     [{..Pi,pH,7.09},{...GENTEK...}...]
```

.
.
.

I want to group data recorded on the same date in one row.

How can I achieve this? Is there a way?

I pulled the data by time period and then grouped it with a python for loop, but this was a very long process in large time intervals.

Comment: Please post code not image links.

Comment: I don't understand the desired result. Where dos  `PULSAR` or `GENTEK` come from. It's not part of the sample data. Also: the result looks a little bit like JSON but it isn't valid JSON.

Comment: Further you state *group data recorded on the same date in one row*. However, your desired results are inconsistent with that statement they show grouped by the minuet. Which do you want `group by day` or `group by minuet`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you meant to group data on the same value of `datetime` column, you can do this:

```
select datetime,
       array_to_json(array_agg(json_build_object(parameter, raw)))  as parameters
  from a_table
 group by 1
 order by 1;
```

Result:

```
datetime               |parameters                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
-----------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2022-12-02 16:13:00.000|[{"AKM" : 16.02},{"KOi" : 25.98},{"AkisHizi" : 0.83},{"Sicaklik" : 17.87},{"Debi" : 27.85},{"CozunmusOksijen" : 5.91},{"Iletkenlik" : 2221.36},{"pH" : 7.25},{"AKM" : 38.64},{"KOi" : 26.17},{"AkisHizi" : 0.52},{"Sicaklik" : 12.46},{"Debi" : 1.32},{"Cozunmu|
2022-12-02 16:14:00.000|[{"KABIN NEM" : 62.28},{"KABIN SICAKLIK" : 13.99},{"AKM" : 6.02},{"KOi" : 21.36},{"AkisHizi" : 0.56},{"Sicaklik" : 21.6},{"Debi" : 10.35},{"CozunmusOksijen" : 0.32},{"Iletkenlik" : 7325.54},{"pH" : 7.57},{"KABIN NEM" : 21.71},{"KABIN SICAKLIK" : 16.5},{"A|
2022-12-02 16:15:00.000|[{"Günlük Debi" : 5363.51},{"KABIN NEM" : 34.65},{"KABIN SICAKLIK" : 20.25},{"AKM" : 6.52},{"KOi" : 12.71},{"AkisHizi" : 0.54},{"Sicaklik" : 14.41},{"Debi" : 5.09},{"CozunmusOksijen" : 5.86},{"Iletkenlik" : 1933.55},{"pH" : 7.24}]                         |
2022-12-02 16:16:00.000|[{"Günlük Debi" : 3423.89},{"KABIN NEM" : 36.27},{"KABIN SICAKLIK" : 20.18},{"AKM" : 4.54},{"KOi" : 24.4},{"AkisHizi" : 0.59},{"Sicaklik" : 13.53},{"Debi" : 3.04},{"CozunmusOksijen" : 5.05},{"Iletkenlik" : 1125.64},{"pH" : 7.09}]                          |
2022-12-02 16:17:00.000|[{"KABIN NEM" : 20.22},{"KABIN SICAKLIK" : 6.49},{"AKM" : 6.36},{"KOi" : 30.12},{"AkisHizi" : 0.82},{"Sicaklik" : 20.36},{"Debi" : 16.15},{"CozunmusOksijen" : 2.45},{"Iletkenlik" : 1570.75},{"pH" : 7.48}]                                                   |
```

Comment: I guess the `array_to_json()`, `array_agg()` and `json_build_object()` got the OP started, so well deserved as the /winning answer/ ... but ... `group by 1` ?!? Ughh...